# Apache cannot start, "access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions" error

Tags: apache, laragon

This problem shows up when I click on "Start All" in Laragon version 2.0.5.

[image: Laragon Problem]

How can I fix this?

Comment: You have another service which is running on port 80. You should stop it first (Check if it is Skype or something else)

Answer (score 0):

Menu > Preferences > Services & Ports > change the port to 8888.

Comment: UPDATE 2020:

This time, I had oracle database installed so even the port 8888 was not working. I changed the port to 2222 and it works perfectly fine now.